# Js GraalJS create txt files

Tags: javascript, file, save, txt, graaljs

Is there a way on GraalJS to create a txt file.

https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/JavaScriptCompatibility.md

I'm using maestro which uses GraalJS as jsEngine: https://maestro.mobile.dev/advanced/javascript/graaljs-support

I would like to create a txt file.

Can you give me a hand?